# ¿Porque no funciona el test?

Tags: java, spring-boot, test, junit, mockito

Llevo varios días enfrentado me a un problema que no se donde corregirlo. Les pongo el código:
Test:

```
class ServidorServiceTest {
    
    @Mock
    TransManager transManager;
    @Mock
    BuscarServidorPort buscarServidorPort;
    
    @InjectMocks
    private ServidorService servidorService;

    private final Connection con = null;
    final Servidor servidor = new Servidor(1, "splunk-server", "192.168.1.10", "Windows NT");
    private List<Servidor> servidores;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws Exception {
        servidores = new ArrayList<>();
        servidores.add(new Servidor());

        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        Mockito.when(transManager.connect()).thenReturn(con);
    }

    @Test
    void testBuscarServidorPorId() throws PersistenceCustomException {
        final BuscarServidorUseCase.BuscarPorId buscarPorId = new BuscarServidorUseCase.BuscarPorId();
        buscarPorId.setId(servidor.getId());
        Mockito.when(buscarServidorPort.buscarServidorPorId(any(Connection.class), any(Servidor.class))).thenReturn(
                new Servidor()
        );
        Servidor servidorRespuesta = servidorService.buscarServidorPorId(buscarPorId);
        
        assertNotNull(servidorRespuesta);
        assertEquals(servidor, servidorRespuesta);
        
        try {
            Mockito.when(buscarServidorPort.buscarServidorPorId(con, servidor)).thenThrow(PersistenceCustomException.class);
            servidorService.buscarServidorPorId(buscarPorId);
        }catch(ApplicationException e) {
            assertTrue(true);
        }
    }

    @Test
    void testBuscarTodos() throws PersistenceCustomException {
        Mockito.when(buscarServidorPort.buscarTodos(con)).thenReturn(servidores);
        List<Servidor> respuesta = servidorService.buscarTodos();

        assertNotNull(respuesta);
        assertEquals(servidores, respuesta);
        assertFalse(respuesta.isEmpty());
        assertEquals(1, respuesta.size());

        try {
            Mockito.when(buscarServidorPort.buscarTodos(con)).thenThrow(PersistenceCustomException.class);
            servidorService.buscarTodos();
        }catch(ApplicationException e) {
            assertTrue(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Servicio:

```
@Service
public class ServidorService implements BuscarServidorUseCase {

    @Autowired
    private TransManager transManager;
    @Autowired
    private BuscarServidorPort buscarServidorPort;

    @Override
    public Servidor buscarServidorPorId(BuscarPorId buscarPorId) {
        Connection con = null;
        Servidor servidorRespuesta;
        Servidor servidorEnviado = new Servidor();
        servidorEnviado.setId(buscarPorId.getId());

        try {
            con = transManager.connect();
            servidorRespuesta = buscarServidorPort.buscarServidorPorId(con, servidorEnviado);
        } catch(PersistenceCustomException e) {
            throw new ApplicationException(e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {
            if(con != null) {
                transManager.closeFinally();
            }
        }
        
        return servidorRespuesta;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Servidor> buscarTodos() {
        List<Servidor> servidoresRespuesta;
        Connection con = null;
        
        try {
            con = transManager.connect();
            servidoresRespuesta = buscarServidorPort.buscarTodos(con);
        } catch(PersistenceCustomException e) {
            throw new ApplicationException(e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {
            if(con != null) {
                transManager.closeFinally();
            }
        }
        
        return servidoresRespuesta;
    }
}
```

Mi problema es que siempre recibo el siguiente fallo al ejecutar la clase de test:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: not <null>

    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:39)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail(Assertions.java:117)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertNotNull.failNull(AssertNotNull.java:47)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertNotNull.assertNotNull(AssertNotNull.java:36)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertNotNull.assertNotNull(AssertNotNull.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull(Assertions.java:283)
    at com.udemy.gestioninfraestructuraapi.application.services.ServidorServiceTest.testBuscarServidorPorId(ServidorServiceTest.java:56)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
...
```

No entiendo el porque de este error si el objeto se inicializa cuando se se le pasa al thenReturn().
He probado a pasar le el objeto de tipo Servidor llamado servidor al thenReturn(), he probado a setear los valores a la variable buscarPorId, a no setear se los, pero nada funciona ...
Por favor, ¿Podría alguien ayudarme?

Muchas gracias, un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que estoy viendo en tu código, en el método setUp() de los test estás mockeando la respuesta del método transManager.connect(), pero si te fijas estas devolviendo un objecto Connection que es null porque los has iniciado a null arriba.

Entonces en tu código real, en la clase ServidorService cuando invocas al método buscarServidorPorId de la clase BuscarServidorPort, le estas pasando un parámetro Connection null y seguramente dentro del código del método es necesario para poder construir el resultado que se le asingará a la variable servidorRespuesta.

Entonces este método seguro que esta devolviendo un null y por tanto la variable servidorRespuesta tendrá el valor null y por eso se incumple el Assert que tienes         assertNotNull(servidorRespuesta);